# Weblogic 12.2.1 validation.xml parsing error

Tags: bean-validation, weblogic12c

I have an ear file that has a validation.xml file in one of its ejb modules when I want to deploy it on Weblogic 12.2.1, then the Weblogic throws the following exception:

```
    <BEA-000000> <Error parsing validation.xml synchronously
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:418)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.ValidationXMLReader.parseValidationXML(ValidationXMLReader.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.ValidationXMLReader.call(ValidationXMLReader.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.BeanValidationHelper.parseValidationXml(BeanValidationHelper.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.BeanValidationHelper.getConstraintsMap(BeanValidationHelper.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.BeanValidationHelper.isConstrained(BeanValidationHelper.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBBeanValidator.isConstrainedObject(JAXBBeanValidator.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBBeanValidator.shouldValidate(JAXBBeanValidator.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.validateAndBuildJAXBElement(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.unmarshal(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:640)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.privilegedactions.Unmarshal.run(Unmarshal.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.privilegedactions.Unmarshal.run(Unmarshal.java:20)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.ValidationXmlParser.run(ValidationXmlParser.java:201)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.ValidationXmlParser.unmarshal(ValidationXmlParser.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.ValidationXmlParser.parseValidationXml(ValidationXmlParser.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getBootstrapConfiguration(ConfigurationImpl.java:353)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.ValidationExtension.<init>(ValidationExtension.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ServiceLoader.prepareInstance(ServiceLoader.java:240)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ServiceLoader.loadService(ServiceLoader.java:214)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ServiceLoader.loadServiceFile(ServiceLoader.java:182)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ServiceLoader.reload(ServiceLoader.java:162)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ServiceLoader.iterator(ServiceLoader.java:297)
    at com.oracle.injection.provider.weld.BasicDeployment.getExtensions(BasicDeployment.java:106)
    at com.oracle.injection.provider.weld.WeldInjectionContainer.initialize(WeldInjectionContainer.java:92)
    at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIAppDeploymentExtension.initCdi(CDIAppDeploymentExtension.java:64)
    at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIAppDeploymentExtension.activate(CDIAppDeploymentExtension.java:41)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.AppDeploymentExtensionFlow.activate(AppDeploymentExtensionFlow.java:39)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:753)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:263)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:67)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:601)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:171)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:121)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:343)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:895)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1422)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:454)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:181)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:643)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:617)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:397)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
```

The validation.xml file's content shows in the below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<validation-config
        xmlns="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/configuration"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
                    http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/configuration
                    validation-configuration-1.1.xsd"
        version="1.1">
</validation-config>
```

How to deploy ear file with validation.xml on weblogic 12.2.1?

Comment: any luck with that? I am having the exact same problem

Comment: I moved validation.xml file from ejb module to META-INF of ear file and fixed

Answer (score 0):

It drives me crazy too. I tried to downgrade bean validation to 1.0, but did not help.

[Here](https://community.oracle.com/message/13547547#13547547) they suggest to ignore it since it is warning only, set the logger to SEVERE level.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with web application.

In my case validation.xml was in one of my jars. I was able to fix the problem by moving the file directly to the war that was being deployed.

In case of ear file I believe the same solution should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug in EclipseLink/TopLink (which is used for JPA and JAXB binding in WLS 12.2.1 and upwards). I opened a FORUM entry in the EclipseLink forum: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1759047/#msg_1759047

Summary: They try to read the validation.xml resource like this:

```
URL validationXml = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("META INF/validation.xml");
```

and then:

```
new File(validationXml.toURI())
```

but the toURI contains an URI that looks like this:

```
 The URL.toString is: zip:/local/saladin/wls12/weblogic/12.2.1.0.0/domains/XXXX/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/xxxx-application_1.5.5_dev-SNAPSHOT/s86txs/lib/xxx-xxxx-xxxxdatamodel-1.5.5_dev-SNAPSHOT.jar!/META-INF/validation.xml
```

So this is not a file, and therefore it cannot work.

The correct way would be to get the resource as Stream and not as File. But as to a solution, I don't know really how to fix it without modifying the EclipseLink source code. It is quite ugly to have those Warnings in the logfile and not being able to do anything about it.